# is there built-in way to make DevExpress XtraGrid GridView column headers/captions diagonal to save horizontal space?

Tags: image, devexpress, xtragrid, text-formatting, columnheader

I have a whole bunch of very narrow columns in a DevExpress GridView and I want to save on column header width by making the caption text (which is too wide even at 3-4 letter abbreviations) slanted / diagonal. Well, so I guess I could get rid of text captions and replace them with pictures of diagonal text, at least if GridView will allow sufficient height for the header.

Is there any built-in way to just display the rotated text without going the image way? I don't think I am the first programmer out there trying to squeeze out horizontal space like that, so this doesn't sound like an outlandish thing to support in a popular grid component :-)

If not, and so I do have to use an image for column header, any relevant suggestions or warnings?

Comment: That's an excellent question. Have you contacted DevExpress support? The only thing that I can think of at the moment is GridView.CustomDrawColumnHeader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XtraGrid does not provide a built in functionality to show column header captions this way.  However, this can be done within the [CustomDrawColumnHeader](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawColumnHeadertopic) event handler.  We have posted a tutorial showing how this can be done.  By default, it should be located at:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress 2010.2 Demos\Components\WinForms\XtraGrid\CS\GridTutorials\GridVerticalHeaders

NOTE, as this feature is implemented using custom draw.  It means that this text is only  painted this way. Custom drawn text won't be exported or printed.

Comment: got it, thanks. I notice that you did not in any way address my thoughts about using a predefined bitmap image (which could also be a small icon, not necessarily a rotated text) as a column header. Is that generally not a good idea?

Comment: This is not a bad idea.  In fact, the thing I suggested to you is just the same.  You are painting a text within the column header area.  I do not like the idea of a predefined bitmaps, because the end-user can resize a column and thus you will have to also resize your bitmap.  So, its clearness will not be ideal.  That is why I like my idea more.

Comment: Here is a link to one such question on the DevExpress support website:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q268892